# Is there a way for os.system to not return an exit code?

Tags: python, exit, os.system

I'm using `os.system` to call system commands, but they always return the command output *and* the exit code.

Is there a way to get `os.system` **not** to return the exit code, and just the command output, or is there a better way to call system commands without returning an exit code? Parsing the exit code out would be a bit of a pain. Thanks!

Comment: It only returns the exit code, not the output. The output is sent to standard output, not returned.

Comment: If you want more flexibility, use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Is there a way for a process to not have an exit code? No.

Is there a better way to run subprocesses than `os.system()`? Definitely. The `os.system` documentation actually tries to convince you to use `subprocess` instead.